# Hashcode return integer value

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

Im trying to understand what to return in a hashcode method.. For a string i know that ive to return(example) name.hashcode(). But what do i return for a int variable? ive seen different examples when they return the variable number x 1 000, but never understanded why.

Can anyone please explain for me how to return a integer value.

Comment: I don't understand either why one would multiply by 1000. Often just returning the value should be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: This question gives all you need to know to understand hashCode and its purpose and how to implement it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: Multiplying by 1000 is a very bad choice as it restricts the set of possible results. Note that the result will always have the last three bits set to 0.

Comment: It could always return `5` and that would be perfectly legit (though non-optimal).  Returning the number itself is fine, though somehow "hashing" the number is probably a little better, in case the user of the value does not hash the value appropriately.  (Eg, HashMap uses `h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12); return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);` to "mix up" the bits a little.)  However, java.lang.Integer simply returns the value, so that's good enough in Oracle's view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class `Foobar`:

```
public class Foobar {
  private final int myInt;

  ... constructor ...

  public int hashCode() {
    return Integer.hashCode(myInt);
  }
}
```

Since Java 8, the method `Integer.hashCode` exists. Otherwise, you can use `Integer.valueOf(myInt).hashCode()`.

**Note:** [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java), you'll read that hashCode and equals should not be based on mutable field, that's why I put `final` in declaration of `myInt`. In practice, it depends on use case (for example, `Set` based on a generated id in `OneToMany` in JPA) and where come your data.

Now as for the "good" `hashCode`, since it is used for hash based collection (map, set), you need to have a good repartition: imagine you return `myInt % 1000`, which means a value between 0 and 999; then this `HashSet` will not be efficient:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(20); // initial capacity of 20
set.add(0);    // 0   [[0]]
set.add(1000); // 0   [[0, 1000]]
set.add(2000); // 0   [[0, 1000, 2000]]
set.add(3000); // 0   [[0, 1000, 2000, 3000]]
set.add(20);   // 20 -> 20 % 20 => 0 [[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 20]]
set.add(21);   // 1  -> 1  % 20 => 1 [[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 20], [1]]
```

In comments, and in the following order:

- `hashCode` returned by `myInt % 1000`
- if not trivial, `index` in internal `HashSet` array.
- content of `HashSet`

The first four values (0 to 3000) will be stored at the same place, 20 will also be stored at the same place, but 21 at another place. Looking up a value require to iterate over the five values.

- For Java Integer, it is the value (here, you could return `myInt` instead of calling `Integer.hashCode`)
- For Java Long, it is some xor (using ^); see `Long.hashCode`.
- For collection, it is in general the sum of `P * o.hashCode()` where P is a prime number; see `Arrays.hashCode`

But I don't remember the exact answer as to why you should use a prime number.